# How do I replace a specific word within a line in a file?

Tags: c++

## My Text File:

```
Name    G    M    S 
Cart    1    0    1
Jane    0    1    0
```

## What I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void scoreChanger();
string line;
int main()
{

    string yn;
    int ctr = 0;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("WiiTourney.txt");
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "This is your current score table: " << endl;
        while(getline(infile, line))
        {
            ctr++;
            cout << line << endl;
            cout << ctr << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    }
    infile.close();

        cout << endl;

        cout << "Would you like to change the scores? " << endl;
        cin >> yn;
        transform(yn.begin(), yn.end(), yn.begin(), ::tolower);

        if (yn == "yes")
        {
            scoreChanger();
        }
        else
        {
            infile.close();
            return 0;
        }

  return 0;
}
void scoreChanger()
{
    string name;
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("WiiTourney.txt");
    if (outfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Who won the game? " << endl;
        cin >> name;
        transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), ::tolower);
        if (name == "jane")
        {
            while(getline(outfile, line))
            {
                cout << line << endl;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < line.length(); x++)
        {
            if (line[x] == 8 && line[x] != 'G')
            {

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error opening file. " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

## What I want it to do:

Let's say I wanted to be able to add 1 point to the Games column(G) only for Cart. The problem for me is that I only want to change the `1` in the `G` column and I know that I would encounter problems by just looping through and searching for instances where 1 comes up because there could be multiple `1`'s in one line. **I am also getting the error on the line `while(getline(outfile, line))` that says "no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ofstream&, std::string&)'"**

Thank you, your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Use `cstdlib` in C++ rather than `stdlib.h`.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: No need to use it at all. OP should, however, be including `cctype` for `std::tolower`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought was that the structure of the table is very uniform, so you could determine the position of a specific score using columns and rows.

Because the names are the only elements with variable length (assuming the scores don't go above 9, because that would give 2 characters), I would first read the first word of every row and input this into an array of names.

From this you can find specific elements using the row and column indices. If C++ doesn't contain a function to get characters based on row and column indices, I would loop through the file and add each character to the corresponding position in a 2-dimensional array.

For example:

```
characters[0][0]
```

would return N, from the start of "Names".

And of course to retrieve the score you incorporate the length of the name the specific line to get the value:

```
characters[names[0].length()+1][1]
```

This would return the score under G for the first name in the list.

Comment: thanks but I am still getting the error: "no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ofstream&, std::string&)'"

Comment: You can't call `getline` on a `ofstream`.  That makes no sense.  You call `getline` on _input_ streams.

Comment: @paddy Then how am I supposed to read each line in order to replace the value in it?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, but have you considered using [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Either open the file as `fstream` for read _and_ write, or change your code to read strings into a `vector` and then write that vector back out in a separate step.  If your file is not _massive_ or the word being replaced is a _different length_ than the replacement then the latter option is probably better.